# JsonObjectRequest shows empty ListView from JSON

Tags: android, json, listview, android-volley

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to use a Singleton for retrieve and populate a ListView for an Android App using Android Studio with the latest version of Volley and I'm having problem when I have to show the information.

The JSON I get from my server is fine, and when I create a product everything seems fine, but the ListView is not populated.

Can you show me some light? I have tried a lot of tutorials and examples and I don't know my ListView is still empty, because I have checked that the products are created in my function.

Here you are my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class ListadoProductos extends Activity {

// URL of object to be parsed
String url = "https://www.mywebsite.com/products.json";

// Key JSON
String key = "lista_productos";

// Map
List<Map<String,String>> productoList = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.products);

    // Get the latest products
    initJSON();

    // Show the information
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listv);
    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, productoList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] {key}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
    listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
}

private HashMap<String, String> createProducto(String nameTitle, String name){
    HashMap<String, String> employeeNameNo = new HashMap<String, String>();
    employeeNameNo.put(nameTitle, name);
    return employeeNameNo;
}

private void initJSON(){

    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try{
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray(key);

                // Show 10 products
                for(int i = 0; i<10;i++){
                    JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                    String name = jsonChildNode.getString("nombre");
                    String outPut = name;
                    productoList.add(createProducto(key, outPut));
                }
            }
            catch(JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("Error", error.toString());
        }
    });

    // Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
    MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
}
}
```

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the server call is not in MainThread so when you initialize simpleAdapter the productoList is probably empty,you have to initialize the adapter in onResponce method so just simply move

```
SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, productoList, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] {key}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
```

to your onResponse(JSONObject response) method

Comment: Hi @Farid, I tried to move it but it's showing the following error: Error:(109, 69) error: incompatible types: <anonymous Listener<JSONObject>> cannot be converted to Context

Comment: instead of "this" use "ListadoProductos.this"